# Proper way testing that String belongs to subset of constants (Java)

Tags: java, string, enums, subset

**Goal:**

- Represent subset of Strings created from Strings defined in abstract class
- test if string on input belongs to given subset

**Initial solution:**

Let's have list of possible events.

```
/**
* List of events.
*/
public abstract class EventKeys {

     public static final String KEY_EVENT_1 = "EVENT_1";
     public static final String KEY_EVENT_2 = "EVENT_2";
     public static final String KEY_EVENT_3 = "EVENT_3";
     public static final String KEY_EVENT_4 = "EVENT_4";
     public static final String KEY_EVENT_5 = "EVENT_5";
     public static final String KEY_EVENT_6 = "EVENT_6";
     public static final String KEY_EVENT_7 = "EVENT_7";
     //etc ..
}
```

I want make subset of these events for example events 1,3,5 and only for these events allow some action. The goal is make method boolean isEventAllowed(String eventKey) which will say if event belongs to subset of allowed events.

The really naive way to do this is:

```
/**
* Allow only events 1,3,5
*/
private isEventAllowed(String eventKey) {

    if(eventKey.equals(EventKeys1.KEY_EVENT_1)) {
        return true;
    } else if(eventKey.equals(EventKeys1.KEY_EVENT_3)) {
        return true;
    }  else if(eventKey.equals(EventKeys1.KEY_EVENT_3)) {
        return true; 
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The I feel this approach is not very convinient. I need better way to **represent the subset of strings and provide action does input string belongs to defined subset?**

**Other possible solutions:** 
As other options i was thinking about other two options, but I'm still not sure if its good way to do it. 
1)enum - create enum of strings

- Put in enum: EventKeys1.KEY_EVENT_1, EventKeys1.KEY_EVENT_2, EventKeys1.KEY_EVENT_3
- Test does String keyEvent belons to defined enum?

2) list

- create list `List<String> subset` and put there 
  EventKeys1.KEY_EVENT_1, EventKeys1.KEY_EVENT_2, EventKeys1.KEY_EVENT_3
- test if String keyEvent belongs to list subset

**PLEASE READ THIS BEFORE ANSWER**:

- class EventKeys is given, can't be changed, main set of options
- I need somehow represent subset
- I need advice for better implementation of method isAllowedEvent(String keyEvent) which returns true if input string
  belongs to defined subset

Comment: Consider using a `java.util.Set` (e.g., `java.util.HashSet`, `java.util.TreeSet`, ...)

Comment: @B.Kemmer at the moment in code, later maybe from in some configuration file which will be mapped anyway to KeyEvent abstract class somehow. Usecase is that on the events in abstract class is done some action I need to do some other action only on some events and need to somehow represent the subset. According comments most suitable would be probably HashSet + contains(eventKey)
It's clear and easy customizable and deffinitelly better than if/else if solution

Comment: @jameslarge thanks for a hint HashSet would be probably what I want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
    private boolean isEventAllowed(String eventKey) {
      return Arrays.asList(KEY_EVENT_1, KEY_EVENT_3, KEY_EVENT_5).contains(eventKey);
    }
```

Readability could be improved following John Fergus' comment by using something like this:

```
    private static List<String> SUBSET = Arrays.asList(KEY_EVENT_1, KEY_EVENT_3, KEY_EVENT_5);

    private boolean isEventAllowed(String eventKey) {
      return SUBSET.contains(eventKey);
    }
```

Comment: OP - How configurable is your 'subset'? You could define the individual keys and then also define the 'subset' into Arrays so that you can do EventKeys.ASubSet.contains(eventKey) on it?

Comment: I will probably use Set<String> subset = new HashSet<String>(); for subset instead of Arrays.asList but idea is still same. Thx

Answer (score 0):

While a `Set` holding the allowed values is usually the preferred option, there are also possible syntactical improvements for your original code which you should become aware of, as their general pattern applies to other situations as well.

A statement like

```
if(condition1)
    action;
else if(condition2)
    /* (same) */ action;
…
```

is redundant and may be replaced by

```
if(condition1 || condition2)
    action;
…
```

similarly

```
if(condition)
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

is redundant and may (or even should) be replaced by

```
return condition;
```

Putting both together, your original code becomes

```
private boolean isEventAllowed(String eventKey) {
    return eventKey.equals(EventKeys1.KEY_EVENT_1)
        || eventKey.equals(EventKeys1.KEY_EVENT_3)
        || eventKey.equals(EventKeys1.KEY_EVENT_5);
}
```

Alternatively, you can use a `switch` statement:

```
private boolean isEventAllowed(String eventKey) {
    switch(eventKey) {
        case EventKeys1.KEY_EVENT_1:
        case EventKeys1.KEY_EVENT_3:
        case EventKeys1.KEY_EVENT_5:
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```

Not everyone likes this coding style, but that’s more an issue of project or company policies. There are situation, where such a `switch` statement still is the cleanest solution. One advantage over `if` statements and even the `Set` approach is that the compiler will immediately shout if you mistakenly name the same constant twice rather than the intended constant (a typical copy&paste error), like you do in your third `if` statement where you use `KEY_EVENT_3` instead of the intended `KEY_EVENT_5`…